# Storing database connectivity configuration in a table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have used multiple databases in a laravel project. The database configuration settings are defined in `database.php`.

What if I want to get connected to multiple databases by fetching configuration from database table. I don't want to store whole of the configurations in database.php file. I will store the configuration in a database table.

This works smoothly

```
    $someModel = new SomeModel;
    $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');
    $something = $someModel->find(1);
```

when I have defined mysql2 in `database.php` but I want to keep configurations in database instead of database.php file. There will be just one database and it will have a table to store configurations.

Comment: So you want to keep the information to connect to a DB inside the DB itself? Isnt this kind of like locking your keys in your car?

Comment: but at least you have to connect database for getting other db credentials.

Comment: I would be very cautious when it comes to storing credentials in DBs themselves, if you are not 100% sure your code is safe from SQL injection then you could be in a world of hurt.

Comment: I am talking about multiple databases guys, @Wobbles